# Adding Submenu in Navigation Bar

Tags: css, html

How can I shift the submenu in right through CSS:

[image]

I want to add a submenu in the navigation and shift to right if you look at the navigation when we hover the submenu and it will come in the sub menu not in the submenu

```
<nav class="main-menu navbar-main-slide">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-main">
      <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown">
         <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle border-hover-color1" href="about.html">COMPANY <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Who are We?</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">What we stand for?</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Management</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Main Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Consulting services &amp; Lab</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Events &amp; Tradeshows</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
         <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle border-hover-color1">Advanced Packaging <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
               <a  href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle border-hover-color1">Rust Prevention at its Best <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
               <ul class="dropdown-toggle dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">VCI films &amp; Bags</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">VCI paper </a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Inbox Desiccants</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Propadry container Desiccant</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Vacuum Barrier Bags</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Rust Preventive Oil</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Cleaning Media &amp; Solutions</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">VCI emitters</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
               <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle border-hover-color1">Advanced Rust Removal <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Neutral Rust Remover</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Acidic Rust Remover</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
               <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle border-hover-color1">Technology Driven Cleaners <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
               <ul class="dropdown-toggle dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Aqueous cleaners for Ferrous Metals</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Aqueous cleaners for Universal Metals</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Solvent cleaners for Universal Metals</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
         <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle border-hover-color1" href="#">Industry Centric Packaging <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
         <ul class="dropdown-toggle dropdown-menu">
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
               <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle border-hover-color1" href="#">Accessories <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Tapes </a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Strapping Solutions </a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sealing &amp; Wrapping Machines</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
               <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle border-hover-color1" href="#">Carefully Designed Inner packaging <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
               <ul class="dropdown-toggle dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">AIR pad</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Bubble wrap</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">LDPE Bags (Stretch Film &amp; Shrink Film)</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Moulded Pulp packaging</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
               <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle border-hover-color1" href="#">Power Packed Load Securing <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
               <ul class="dropdown-toggle dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Dunn age Bags</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Lashing Belts &amp; Buckles </a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Shock absorber void guards</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Shock, Tilt &amp; Humidity indicators </a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
               <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle border-hover-color1" href="#">Outer Packaging <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
               <ul class="dropdown-toggle dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Honey Comb Boxes</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Corrugated Plastic Boxes</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Corrugated Paper Boxes</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Angle Board &amp; Protector</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Wooden &amp; Plywood Boxes</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Wooden ,Plywood &amp; Paper pallets</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">SLIP SHEETS</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Heavy Machine Packaging</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contract Packaging</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown">
         <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle border-hover-color1" href="about.html">News &amp; Media <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Packaging Facts</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Packaging Tips</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Events &amp; Tradeshows</a></li>
            <li><a href="blog.html">Blogs</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT US</a></li>
      <li><a class="btn_header_search" href="#"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a></li>
   </ul>
   <div class="search-form-modal transition">
      <form class="navbar-form header_search_form">
         <i class="fa fa-times search-form_close"></i>
         <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
         </div>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn_search customBgColor">Search</button>
      </form>
   </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: share css also..

Comment: I have pulled your image into the question so people can see it immediately; this might help you get more interest in your question.  I have also removed some of the indentation in your code to make it more viewable on smaller screens.  However, I think your question is confusing to read; especially when you say "it will come in the sub menu not in the submenu".  I don't understand what you are asking in order to improve the phrasing of your question.

Comment: You might also want to reduce the HTML that you have included to just the bare minimal to reproduce the problem you want help with, and, as @LIJINSAMUEL has suggested, you should include the relevant CSS in another code section in your question.